# .NET Core 3 WPF and Paths

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I'm playing with .NET Core 3 and its support for WPF on Visual Studio 2019. I've created a canvas and would like to draw a geometry from code. I'm initialliy attempting to do this by binding the Canvas' Path Data dependency property to a PathGeometry in my ViewModel, i.e.,

```
<Path Data="{Binding PathGeometry}"/>
```

and then setting the PathGeometry in my ViewModel, something like

```
    public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {   

        public PathCanvasViewModel()
        {   
            var arcSegment = new ArcSegment
            {
                // INVALID in .NET Core 3 lib
                Point = new System.Windows.Point()
            };

            var pathFigure = new PathFigure();
            pathFigure.Segments.Add(arcSegment);

            PathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        }

        public PathGeometry PathGeometry { get; }
    }
```

However, the view model won't build due to `System.Windows.Point` not being available in the `System.Windows` namespace. I presume this is because my view model is defined in a pure .NET Core 3 library - if I install the preview nuget package `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` then I'll have access to `Point` in `System.Windows` and the application will build.

Now I'm confused, as the docs for [ArcSegment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.arcsegment?view=netframework-4.8) say it supports `.NET Core 3.0 Preview 7` as do the docs for [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.arcsegment.point?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_ArcSegment_Point), and I'm running that version of .NET Core. So why can I build my .NET Core 3 view model library defining an `ArcSegment`, but as soon as I try to specify a `Point` for that `ArcSegment` I get a build failure?

Comment: Interestingly the docs do not state that the struct `Point` is supported for .NET Core 3.0... than how can `ArcSegment` be .NET Core compatilble, may this be a mistake in the docs?

Comment: @Ackdari Yes, a little strange. Have raise an issue on github: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1496

Answer (score 0):

To save people a click here was the resolution from GitHub issue

> @jdbriaris, the problems with documentation notwithstanding (thanks
>   for bringing this to our attention - its greatly appreciated!), you
>   will not be able to use WPF types without referencing
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App. This includes System.Windows.Point, as
>   well as System.Windows.Media.ArcSegment.
>
> There are some exceptions to this generality - e.g., some types in
>   System.IO.Packaging namespace - that will be available in
>   Microsoft.NetCore.App, and will also continue to be available in
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App through type-forwards in WindowsBase.dll
>   (as they used to in .NET Framework).
>
> The general idea is that WPF and WinForms reside in
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.